# How to increase query specific timeout in VoltDB

Tags: voltdb

In VoltDB Community edition When I am uploading a CSV file (size: 550Mb)for more than 7 times and then performing basic aggregation operations, it’s showing query timeout. 
But then I tried to increase the query timeout through the web interface and still, it’s showing error as “query specific timeout is 10s”
What should I do if I want to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What does your configuration / deployment file look like? To increase the query timeout, the following code should be somewhere in your deployment.xml file:

```
<systemsettings>
   <query timeout="30000"/>
</systemsettings>
```

Where 30000 is 30 seconds, for example. The cluster-wide query timeout is set when you first initialize the database with voltdb init. You could re-initialize with force a new deployment file with the above section in it:

```
voltdb init --force --config=new_deployment_file.xml
```

Or you could keep the cluster running and simply use:

```
voltadmin update new_deployment_file.xml
```

The section Query Timeout in this part of the docs contains more information as well:

https://docs.voltdb.com/AdminGuide/HostConfigDBOpts.php

Full disclosure: I work at VoltDB.

Comment: Thank you @andrew, but when I tried the above steps and increased the query timeout still it's showing me the error as "query-specific" timeout is 10s even though I have increased it 300s
For Eg:

 A SQL query was terminated after 10.001 seconds because it exceeded the query-specific timeout period. The query-specific timeout is currently 10.0 seconds. The default query timeout is currently 300000.0 seconds and can be changed in the systemsettings section of the deployment file.
    at org.voltdb.sysprocs.AdHoc_RO_SP.run(AdHoc_RO_SP.java:46)

Comment: @KunalMali - how are you invoking the query? Is it through sqlcmd, VMC, or from a client?

Comment: In the VoltDB web interface, on the SQL Query tab, there is a little gear icon next to the Run button, where you can set a query-specific timeout. A query-specific timeout overrides the global default timeout. Perhaps if this is not set, it defaults to 10 seconds, but you should be able to override it.

Comment: @BenjaminBallard I am trying through both sqlcmd and VMC. The above mentioned error is from sqlcmd. 
I tried changing query-specific timeout through that little gear in voltDB web interface but still it's showing as Error: Request Timeout.
Also, it is showing error after 15s whereas I have changed it too 300000ms.
Moreover, I tried changing through VMC Admin tab >  Advanced > Query timeout.